# Changing title of a tooltip in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a glyphicon which represents the "drag to toolbar" icon for a bookmarklet on my page. It also has a tooltip. It works great but with a problem;

I want to show "drag this to your toolbar" text as a tooltip when I hover the glyphicon. But when I do that, after I drag the icon to my toolbar it's name becomes also "drag this to your toolbar" as the browser reads the title attribute just like the tooltip() function do. I already tried to change the title attributes of both anchor and span but didn't worked.

How can I change the tooltip() function to make it read another attribute as my tooltip text so that I can change the title attribute to my website name.

Here is my code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(location.href='http://example.com/create.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href))" title="example.com" onclick="return false">
    <span class="bookmarklet glyphicon glyphicon-link hidden-xs hidden-sm" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="✚ example.com" tooltip-text="drag this to your toolbar"></span>
</a>
```

and also

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bookmarklet").tooltip(); 

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".bookmarklet").tooltip(
    title: function(){
          return $(this).attr('tooltip-text');
           }) 
});
```

Comment: tried again doesn't work :/ When I hover tooltip doesn't appear.